# Any alternative report designers other than the traditional "banded" styles?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, reporting

When I think of reports I think of banded reporting.  Tools like Microsoft Access, Crystal Reports, SSRS and even VisualFox use this.  Dynamic behavior must be anticipated in advance and is controlled through conditional fields, subreports and parameters.  These reports are perfect for financial reports or lists of things where anytime you run this (typically between some date range) the look and feel is predetermined and expected by the user.

However our company requires a solution where any user should be able to change any aspects of the report.  Fields, formatting and layout are all changed anytime a report is run.  It's not a traditional "report" if you will since it's not a somewhat static output.

Resorting to banded reporting in this case would banish some developers to the world of crystal reports since we generate 2-6 reports on any given **day**.  I can't imagine a typical user being happy with having to learn how to use crystal report designer either.

What are some alternative reporting solutions that allow you to build reports without being at the whim of learning an entire reporting suite such as Crystal Reports?  I've added an answer of my own to show a great alternative that we're currently using and hope to get some good input for future use.   The point of this post however is to collect some alternative solutions to the one proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DevExpress Snap**

With some digging we discovered [DevExpress Snap](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Snap/) which allows you to build reports using a Word Processor much like Microsoft Word by dragging fields from a fields toolbox right into the document!  It feels exactly like Microsoft Word with data field drag and drop capabilities.  Fantastic!

We've already created a Template structure so users can save their predetermined layouts as "general" templates to start work off of but nearly every report generated contains different fields and formatting.  Sometimes even images are dropped into the document to illustrate a point.

Now I don't have to be banished to the land of SSRS!  This is an amazing solution though I still generate certain reports (P&L for example) through SSRS since it should be a pre-set reporting style, with it's fields and design locked away from the user.

Comment: After years of use there are many caveats to using this solution.  The biggest is that this is still banded reporting in disguise.  It's convenient for our users to adjust significant figures as they see fit and to drag and drop content right into an active report but be wary, there are performance concerns that have yet to be addressed as well as enhancements that are still missing such as repeating headings on each page.  

These limits are not surprising as their goal is to mimic word but there are compromises here.  Do your research if you decide to use this approach!

Answer (score 1):

The other solution I found that looks pretty powerful and easy to use is [Windward Autotag](http://windward.net/products/autotag/).  It's an actual plug-in for Word that just adds an extra tab at the top of the ribbon for all your report options.  So you can literally design all your reports right in Word.  You put your data wherever you want by going to the Autotag tab added to the ribbon and clicking a button to insert your data where you want it.  I haven't tried it yet, but the website and [demo video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHyW1mMhl4I) look pretty impressive.

Comment: This looks neat, I have to check this one out. Thanks for the input!